# Manually updating component in Angular

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript

When I refresh a component in my Angular application (which uses version 17), the path 'localhost:4200/(path)' becomes 'localhost:4200'. This behavior is repeated with my other three components, with the exception of the HomeComponent. Despite this change in the path, the component is still visible on the screen. The drawback occurs when switching between different components: the page reloads when accessing a component (which should not happen), and transitions to the next component (which is displayed on the screen), but the path is not updated to 'localhost:4200/', except in the case of 'localhost:4200/home'. This behavior is due to the path configuration I have set: { path: '', redirectTo: '/home', pathMatch: 'full' }.

[Before reloading the page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TzUym.png)
[After reloading the page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wemth.png)
[I can still access the other components, but the path is not shown and the page reloads](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OAZlZ.png)
[Proyect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/co2RR.png)

I need to find a solution so that the path (after manually updating)

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution to the problem. In essence, the components contained the `<body></body>`. When you remove the label `<body></body>` from a component and refresh that component's page, the path is not deleted. The HomeComponent path was not deleted because, in its HTML structure, it did not have the `<body></body>`.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).